# search an array list for a specific string of text

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist

how can I look for an word in a array list? in my code I search the array by position using get, but I want to compare a string (from user input) to the elements of the array, and then if it's found print all the elements contained in the position where the string was found.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;import java.util.Scanner;


public class Shoes {
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList shoesList = new ArrayList();



public void Shoe1() {

    int Shoe1;
    String Color1;
    float Size1;
    float Price1;


    System.out.println("Enter model of the shoe: ");
    Shoe1 = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter color of the shoe: ");
    Color1 = input.next();
    System.out.println("Enter size of the shoe: ");
    Size1 = input.nextFloat();
    System.out.println("Enter price of the shoe: ");
    Price1 = input.nextFloat();

    shoesList.add("" + "model: " + Shoe1 + "\n" + "color: " + Color1 +//adds the variables, shoe, color, size and 
            "\n" + "size: " + Size1 + "\n" +"price: " + Price1);        //price to one spot of the array
}



 public void getSpecific(int value){
     //gets and specific value taking input from the user
    int select = value;
    System.out.println(shoesList.get(select));



    }
```

so what i want to do is search by the model of the shoe, say i have a model 1, if i search for "model 1" i want the program to display all the information stored in the position of the array where model 1 is.

Comment: You should create class Shoes and add it to `List<Shoes>`

Answer (score 0):

You have a `List` of `String` you can use either [startsWith(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith%28java.lang.String%29) or [contains(CharSequence)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains%28java.lang.CharSequence%29). However, you should probably move those fields into your `Shoes` class and store instances of `Shoes` in your `List`.

Answer (score 0):

No problem!
So, we want to:

```
1. Loop over the shoeList
2. See which shoe has the text
3. Print that shoe

//Note: Instead of taking an int, its better to take all the String. Example "model 1".

public void printShoe(String value){
for(String shoe : shoeList){ //The sign ":" said that, for every String in shoeList, 
                             //do the following

    if(shoe.contains(value))
       {System.out.println(shoe);break;}//Break will make it not print more than 1 shoe


   }

}
```

Comment: thanks, i appreciate your answers i'm gonna try this.

Answer (score 0):

This method will do it.

```
String getIfContainsUserInput(String userInputString) 
{
     for (String shoeString : shoesList) 
     {
         if (shoeString.matches(".*" + Pattern.quote(userInputString) + ".*"))
           return shoeString;
    }

  return null;
}
```

Comment: Using pattern matching is way too complicated. String.contains("...") is the way to go.